# Rejected edit of question containing two questions to focus on a single one

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I've just had [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5426753) rejected, presumably for making some huge changes to the question.

The original question really contained two questions, one about how to exit a loop and then another about a specific issue that was causing Talend to fail to compile.

The question had more detail on the compilation error (and that needed sorting first anyway) so I answered it and then had my answer accepted. I suggested to the OP to raise a second question about exiting the loop [which they did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041657/how-to-end-tloop-when-desired-criteria-reached).

I then sought to tidy up that first question to put more focus on the compilation error and remove all mention of the looping problems so that it could be more use to others (it could be argued that this might actually be too localised and it's actually pretty poor as the OP simply missed a parenthesis) and to distance it from the other question about controlling while loops in Talend.

Should I have left it as it was? I recognise it was a large edit to make but it seemed to make the two questions more clear because of it.

Comment: Yeah, you changed too much.  The question was already asked and answered anyway, two hours ago.  Time to move on.

Comment: Yeah, I answered it. Two hours also isn't an overly long time on such a slow moving tag (it's a Talend specific question). I mostly wanted to tidy it up so that the second question got the right amount of interest in case other Talend users here on SO had any other useful input on the matter.

Comment: That was a good edit; I've applied it manually and given you what credit I could in the revision note.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of those edits where if you don't notice the revision notes, follow up on those notes, and look very closely, the edit appears to be invalid.  Such edits, while they should in theory be accepted, are frequently rejected because it's actually rather hard to recognize that the edit is correct.  While it should have been approved, I'm not exactly surprised that it wasn't.

As for what to do, ideally you'd either find someone with 2k rep to edit the post, or better still have the author of the post make the edit to the question since it is really a rather radical change.  Trying to go through the review queue here is somewhat of a crapshoot (even more than normal, as this really is a hard edit to review).